# Fresh Ubuntu installation behaving really weird - Windows won't maxmise and network connections don't work

Tags: networking, unity

I have a fresh dual boot Ubuntu installation on a gaming PC that I just built that has been behaving really really strange and I don't know where to start with it. It's exhibiting the two pieces of behavior

- The network connections don't seem to be working. I tried pinging google.com and nothing works. Pinging seems to show that it can resolve google.com's IP but the ping doesn't go and come back like usual. When I ping that IP that it found the first time, that does seem to work though. So as a result it can't resolve anything and I can't get on the internet basically. I check my IP in the network applet in the system tray and both my wireless and wired connections have an IP. And I can ping 192.168.1.1. I also tried disabling one connection and pinging google.com then the other and retrying and neither one of those worked. Neither connection seems to work.
- After about a minute of being logged in the chrome on the windows desktop environment stops responding. Meaning, on the very first thing that I turn on, it works just fine, then after a little while. Clicking the close, minimize, and maximise buttons don't work. Nothing happens. Alt-Tab works. Nothing in the top bar works or the shortcut bar on the left. The whole desktop environment sorta freezes, but only parts of it. So like if Firefox is open widgets inside the firefox window might still work, but I can't do anything with that or load any other window.

This is a dual boot setup, and I doubt that its a faulty hardware issue because the hardware works fine on the Windows partition.

So my usage of Ubuntu grinds to a halt after a minute or two basically. Any ideas of what could be wrong? Or what I should do?

Side note, what happened to Ubuntu? I'm coming back after a few years, and I never used to get these kinds of issues

Comment: A *gaming PC* and yet no mention of the graphics card? Should we assume you installed no drivers? Also of notice is you have two unrelated issues: 1. the performance that most likely is (comparatively) impaired if using any high-end Nvidia graphics and the default open source drivers; 2. The internet access issue which is apparently a DNS problem (change the DND server to Google's 8.8.8.8).

Comment: It's a geforce 1070

Comment: *It's a geforce 1070* so nothing else to add to the previous comment, install the recommended Nvidia drivers at "Additional Drivers".